# A template method taking char array as argument

Tags: c++, c++17

A template method defined in a library has following signature

```
  template<unsigned N>
  void method_from_lib(const char (&url) [N] ){....};
```

I am invoking this method in class, where I would like to have that the `URL` is defined from the outside, i.e. passed through the constructor of my class

```
 class myClass{
    // a member variable of url 
   TYPE? url;

   myClass(Type? url_) : url(url_){};
 
   void run(){ method_from_lib(url) };

   }
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that I dont know what the `Type?` should be so invoking the method becomes compatible.

I intend to use the method from the outside like:

```
myClass my_class = myClass("url_test1");
```

or by passing a std::string

```
std::string url = "test1" ;

myClass my_class = myClass(url);
```

There are a number of workaround that I prefer to avoid:

A solution would be to template  `myClass` but then I would need to explicitly set the number N in the class which is really something I would avoid. Like `myClass<100>("urlWith100)`

Another solution would be to template the `run` method which is something I cannot do in my example (since `run` is an implementation of a another interface (pure virtual) - not shown here)

Are there any other solutions that I could benefit from

Comment: The library function you are showing simply has a `char*` parameter, independent of the value of `N`, because top-level arrays in function parameters are pointers. I don't think that is intentional. It doesn't make any sense. Maybe a reference is missing. It is also weird that it takes a `char`, not a `const char`. This means it can't be directly called with a string literal. Why does the library not offer a non-templated variant of the function that takes a `const char*`? It doesn't make sense to just take fixed-length URLs, since they may be generated at runtime with apriori unknown length.

Comment: I usually store my strings in `std::string`.

Comment: `method_from_lib()` is just an implementation detail that shouldn't dictate the interface of `myClass`. Choose what makes most sense from a _design_ point of view for `myClass`, which is propably `std::string` and possibly a `const char*` overload too. Then you deal with any restriction imposed by a poorly designed library function, e. g. make a temporary copy of the URL into a fixed char array within the `run()` method.

Comment: my bad it does take a const char (& url) [N], and it is the only constructor

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the new information.

Comment: @ATK If this is the only overload, then passing a `std::string` is impossible, since the function requires a fixed length. The best you can do is choose a maximum size and store an array of that size in the class, then fail on any string larger than that maximum. But if that is the case, then the library is practically unusable or there is a specific reason that the library author doesn't want you to pass anything other than string literals.

Comment: It's not a single string, it's an fixed size array of references to const char.
Hit the author of the library with a large trout till they change the interface to `std::array<std::string, N>` or `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think OP might have just mixed that up. In their last comment above it is actually a reference to a `const char` array. An array of references is not allowed anyway.

Comment: @user17732522 Or I was confused about the precedences. The `const char (&url)[N]` is actually parsed more like `&(const char[N])`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're attempting to make sure that the input is exactly N characters long, you could check for it in the constructor and throw an exception if the condition isn't met.

If you're averse to using `std::string` then this would be one way to go:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>

class myClass
{
    //+//////////////
    // members
    //+//////////////
    
    static constexpr std::size_t N = 10;
    char url_[N] = {};
    
public:
    
    //+//////////////
    // lifecycle
    //+//////////////
    
    myClass(const char* url)
    {
        if (std::strlen(url) > N)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("input_too_long_error");
        }
        std::strcpy(url_, url);
    }
};
```

Comment: `const char& (url) [N]` != `char url_[N]`. The library takes an array of strings.